# How Do I Correctly Structure a Function within a Foreach Loop?

Tags: php, function, foreach

I have researched and tried many solutions on how to properly call a function within a foreach loop, and I am still getting an error. Below are the details:

```
    $firstName = "CA";
    $firstNameArr = str_split($firstName);

    foreach ($firstNameArr as $value){

    function getLtr($ltr){

        switch ($ltr) :
           case  "A": return 'The letter is A'; 
           case  "B": return 'The letter is B';
           case  "C": return 'The letter is C';
           default: return 'This is not a valid selection';

        endswitch;
    }   
    echo getLtr($value) . '<br>';
    }
```

The error I receive: "Cannot redeclare getltr() (previously declared in ... first line of function referenced)"

I appreciate your assistance!

Comment: You can't put a function definition inside a loop

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't put the function inside the loop, you call it from within the loop.

```
$firstName = "CA";
$firstNamesArray = str_split($firstName);

foreach ($firstNamesArray as $value) {
    echo getLetter($value) . '<br>';
}

/**
 * The function should be outside the loop.
 * When it's inside, it's getting redeclared every time the loop iterates.
 */
function getLetter($letter) {
    switch ($letter) :
       case  "A": 
            return 'The letter is A'; 
       case  "B": 
            return 'The letter is B';
       case  "C": 
            return 'The letter is C';
       default: 
            return 'This is not a valid selection';
    endswitch;
}
```

Notice I've spelled out your function name and variables.  Don't use abbreviations like that.  Try and write code that is self-documenting, meaning that the function and variable names are meaningful, instead of cryptic abbreviations.

Comment: Thank you for the answer and the additional advice on self-documenting (hence yours being the selected answer)! I am fairly new to coding, and I've gotten mixed up myself trying to learn from other cryptic examples.

Answer (score 4):

Your function should be outside the loop.

Try something like this:

```
$firstName = "CA";
$firstNameArr = str_split($firstName);

foreach ($firstNameArr as $value){
    echo getLtr($value).'<br>';
}

function getLtr($ltr){

    switch ($ltr) :
       case  "A": return 'The letter is A'; 
       case  "B": return 'The letter is B';
       case  "C": return 'The letter is C';
       default: return 'This is not a valid selection';

    endswitch;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

you put the function outside of the foreach loop thats the whole point of the function :)

```
$firstName = "CA";
    $firstNameArr = str_split($firstName);

     function getLtr($ltr){

        switch ($ltr) :
           case  "A": return 'The letter is A'; 
           case  "B": return 'The letter is B';
           case  "C": return 'The letter is C';
           default: return 'This is not a valid selection';

        endswitch;
    } 

    foreach ($firstNameArr as $value){


    echo getLtr($value) . '<br>';
    }
```

Comment: Thank you, as you can tell, I'm a newbie at coding :)